# Query about the tag to use for Questions on SSIS Data Flow tasks

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I was editing "[SSIS - Can you use a parameterised query to populate a Lookup Transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692623/ssis-can-you-use-a-parameterised-query-to-populate-a-lookup-transformation/)", and wanted to add a tag to indicate that it's a question about an [SSIS Data Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx). I didn't see one right away (to my surprise), so I created the [ssis-data-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis-data-flow) tag and created the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis-data-flow/info) at the same time.

Later, I found the [dataflowtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataflowtask) tag. It looks like this has been used for questions about SSIS Data Flows 46 times. Now, the obvious thing would be to add [ssis-data-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis-data-flow) as a synonym for this tag. I would have found the tag that way.

On the other hand, this tag has no tag wiki, and I'm quite sure that far more than 46 of the 8,266 [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis) questions are about data flows.

Maybe we can do something like rename [dataflowtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataflowtask) to [ssis-data-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis-data-flow), and then transfer over my tag wiki edit? It would then be safe for someone to edit data flow questions to add the tag.

But what do you all think?

---

Another reason I ask is that [the last time I created a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/congratulations-eric-lippert-for-finally-winning-the-c-language-badge/62684#62684), I was threatened with suspension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I think both tags are somewhat useless and should be burninated. There's probably 5-7 people that regularly answer questions related to SSIS. In my time, I've never met nor seen anyone that understands the Dataflow components but couldn't explain a Control Flow Task. Plus, I watch the SSIS tag and sometimes the ssis-2012 tag for questions. So, new person writes up a killer SSIS question and only tags it with ssis-data-flow, they might be waiting a long time for an answer.

If we wanted SSIS tags that meant something, perhaps a development versus management (everything related to deployment, scheduling, troubleshooting permissions etc).

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are often 2 schools of thought: compose tags v. composite tags.

For example:

- `ssis-dataflow-task` is a "composite tag" - an all-in-one tag that says it all.
- `ssis` `dataflow` `task` is composition of tags.
- (Disclaimer: this is about tags, not whether the tag should be "dataflow" or "dataflow-task" or "dataflowtask")

It's hard to know when someone will choose the "composite-tag" approach or the composition of tags approach.

And, I am not sure if Synonyms necessarily help in this case.  Also, I often type and watch for matches when I tag my questions, and observe what comes up - further, then I see both the composite style and the component style tags, I bias toward the one with more uses.